# Inconsistency in Yaakov's presents for his brother Esau

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, vayishlach

> עִזִּים מָאתַיִם וּתְיָשִׁים עֶשְׂרִים
>   רְחֵלִים מָאתַיִם וְאֵילִים עֶשְׂרִים׃
>   גְּמַלִּים מֵינִיקוֹת וּבְנֵיהֶם שְׁלֹשִׁים
>   פָּרוֹת אַרְבָּעִים וּפָרִים עֲשָׂרָה
>   אֲתֹנֹת עֶשְׂרִים וַעְיָרִם עֲשָׂרָה׃
>   200 she-goats and 20 he-goats;
>   200 ewes and 20 rams;
>   30 milch camels with their colts;
>   40 cows and 10 bulls;
>   20 she-asses and 10 foals. ([Gen 32.15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.32.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

It has two different kinds of pairs:
**couples** - goats, sheep, cows,
**mother and offspring** - camels and asses.

Why is this difference?

---

Note:

1. in Hebrew, עיר stands for a foal, a grown-up male is called חמור
2. some say פר also stands for עגל not for שור like פר בן בקר

Comment: Is your question why the **couples** were - goats, sheep, cows, and **mother and offspring** were camels and asses? Maybe because one group is kosher and the other not? (Or maybe just random that's what he decided?)

Comment: Have a look at Rash"i. I think he explains some part of this. However, even after I read it, I'm confused.

Comment: עיר per rashi is just a male donkey. חמור is a male or female donkey. Also, Rashi brings a Midrash which says בניהם by the camels is actually בנאיהם (their "builders" i.e. males)